# Grab the text from the nearest span tag using jquery on keyup press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to grab the text from the nearest span tag with the class 'item_price' and save it to a variable - can anyone tell me whats wrong

Also I am trying to grab the 'hidden' input also

```
    $('#ajax_basket').on('keyup','input',function(event) {    
     var qty = $(this).val();
     var item_price = $(this).find('span.item_price').text();
             var hidden_id;
     console.log(qty);
     console.log(item_price);
    });

<form id="ajax_basket">
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="1[rowid]" value="5333a934f53d623eb18c490b57522d93"></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td>Apple iPhone 2G</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="1[qty]" value="1" maxlength="2" size="1" class="input-mini qty"  /></td>
  <td style="text-align:right" class="item_price_row">&#36;<span class="item_price">15.00</span></td>
  <td style="text-align:right" class="sub_total">&#36;15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Apple iPhone 5G</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="1[qty]" value="1" maxlength="2" size="1" class="input-mini qty"  /></td>
  <td style="text-align:right" class="item_price_row">&#36;<span class="item_price">115.00</span></td>
  <td style="text-align:right" class="sub_total">&#36;115.00</td>
</tr>   
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `ajax_basket`

Comment: sorry - that is the id of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to backstep to the parent `tr`, then `find`

```
$('#ajax_basket').on('keyup','input',function(event) {    
    var qty = this.value
    var item_price = $(this).closest("tr").find('span.item_price').text();

    var hidden_id;
    console.log(qty);
    console.log(item_price);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The below line

```
$(this).find('span.item_price').text();
```

gets searches for `span` with class `item_price` among descendents of text box.

Try something like below:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('span.item_price').text();
```